# How to use the 'bullet' character '•'

Tags: symbols

I would like to use this special character - a 'bullet' '•', but LaTeX won't let me. Does anyone know how to use this in LaTeX?

Comment: Does `$\bullet$` work?

Comment: Thank you so much! $\bullet$ = "•"

Comment: `\textbullet` for use in text.